# Data formatting issue : Array to Object. any easy way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, formatting

I tried to format a array to object. it's working fine but I need to know, Is this correct or wrong? any other standard way to do this?.

I used underscoreJS for this.

//What I get from API

"A/a/1" = A -> Category, a -> Subcategory, 1 -> child of subcategory.

```
["A", "A/a", "A/b", "A/a/1", "A/a/2", "B", "B/a"];
```

//Which format i need.

```
[
   {
      "name":"A",
      "parent":"",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"a",
            "parent":"A",
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"1",
                  "parent":"a",
                  "children":[

                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"2",
                  "parent":"a",
                  "children":[

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"b",
            "parent":"A",
            "children":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"B",
      "parent":"",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"a",
            "parent":"B",
            "children":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

MY CODE :

```
var dataObj = function(){
        this.name = "";
        this.parent = "";
        this.administrator = "";
        this.children = [];
      };


  var d_ = []; 

  _.each(data, function(item, index){

        var row = new dataObj();
        var item_array = item.split("/"),
            item_array_length = item_array.length;

          if(item_array.length  == 1){

            row.name = item_array[0];
            d_.push(row);

          } else {

              row.name = item_array[1];
              row.parent = item_array[0];
              var newC = d_[_.findIndex(d_, {name:item_array[0]})];

            if(item_array.length  == 2) {

              newC.children.push(row);

            } else if(item_array.length  == 3) {


              newC.children[_.findIndex(newC.children, {name: item_array[1]})]
                  .children.push({name : item_array[2], parent : item_array[1]});


            }


          }

  });
```

**UPDATE**
The level of subcategory is not limited. "A/a/1/i/n/x/y...."

Comment: sorry but what is the logic behind that? is there anything we can apply? it doesn't really seem to have a very specific logic.

Comment: @briosheje "A/a/1" = A -> Category, a -> Subcategory, 1 -> child of subcategory. all levels was separated with "/". I need to change the format to object (i add the wanted format above.)

Comment: I can see the 'administrator' attribute absent from some of the node in the final output which you are looking for. Please clarify if this is intended and if so what should be the logic behind the same?

Comment: And would like to know other constraints and conditions like if 1. there is any possibility of duplicate elements on your response from the API 2. if the level of nesting is going to be maximum three
.
That will give us a clear idea if the solution should be generic enough to handle all such cases

Comment: @DopedDude don't think about administrator.. The level of subcategory is not limited. "A/a/1/i/n/x/y....". can't limit to any level ( but currently i did for 3 levels). The logic is we need to create the object form a string for generate the level of a product.

Answer (score 2):

I feel your implementation can be improved. Following are the few possibilities:

1. To reduce the processing time the return data structure of the API can be of the form `["A/b", "A/a/1", "A/a/2", "B/a"]` instead of `["A", "A/a", "A/b", "A/a/1", "A/a/2", "B", "B/a"]`
2. `_` library does not seem helping much, the code can be implemented in plain javaScript.
3. The implementation can be made generic enough to handle any level of nested children. The current implementation is limited to level 3.

A simple algorithm I can think of would consist of the following high level steps:

1. Let's call the data served from API as `sampleArray`.
2. for each element of `sampleArray` we have `currentSplittedElementArray = sampleArray[i].split('/');`
3. Let's call required output as `finalOutput`
4. loop through the `finalOutput` and test if the element is already present `finalOutput[i].name === currentSplittedElementArray[0]`
5. If the element is already present then let's loop through the `currentSplittedElementArray` and update the same element of the `finalOutput` with the elements of `currentSplittedElementArray`. (If the element is not already present on the `finalOutput` then let's first create the element on the `finalOutput` and populate it with the elements of `currentSplittedElementArray`)

I know the above algorithm may seem daunting and the steps outlined will include invoking a function repeatedly in a loop or using some sort of recursion. But this is something I would have done if I were to implement something like this.

I am open to any area of improvement/optimization in my approach.